I can't figure why downloading dataset gives error file not found
I try running this code to download the dataset:
    training_data = datasets.EMNIST(
        root="data",
        split="digits",
        train=True,
        download=True,
        transform=ToTensor()
    )

And it gives me the same error every time
Downloading https://www.nist.gov/itl to data\EMNIST\raw\gzip.zip
 58%|█████▊    | 65536/113097 [00:00<00:00, 609759.84it/s]100%|██████████| 113097/113097 
...
...
RuntimeError: File not found or corrupted.

Has anybody an explanation?
